# GitLab pipeline configure

Tags: continuous-integration, tags, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I use GitLab CI for my build action.
I need to build my production env only on master upstream branch and only by a tag.
Now I have something like this:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build_project:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd ./some-dir
    - build-script.sh
  only:
    - master
    - tags
```

Does someone know how should I change my rules?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Do you want the `build_project` job to only run for the master branch and tags?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I just want to run my stage when I make a tag on the master upstream (not fork's) branch

Answer (score 0):

There's an example of how to do this in the Gitab docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#onlyexcept-basic

```
job:
  only:
    - branches@gitlab-org/gitlab
  except:
    - master@gitlab-org/gitlab
    - /^release/.*$/@gitlab-org/gitlab
```